# Java Application does not run one different (Remote PC)

Tags: java, compatibility

I created a java application, made a jar file. 
That jar files runs at my PC (Windows 7, 64 Bit, Java 8 64 Bit) as expected.
But not on the test persons PC, what runs with  WIN 7 32 Bit, 32 Bit java. 
Unfortunately I do not have any access to that box, just some email information about bad behavior of program: It not even shows up the first JFrame but consumes CPU only.
Before travelling 200KM -
Should I include the different Bits (32 vs 64) into consideration?
Or should I just focus on java versions?

Cheers,
Tarik

Comment: If you make a Java App it can run in 32 and 64 bit. What is the error that you getting? What Java are you using? In what version was made the jar file?

Comment: This is impossible for anyone to even speculate on without any kind of code / errors. This will be 100% implementation specific. The best thing you can do is add some debug logging to the application and ask the other party for the log files.

Answer (score 0):

from the control panel, open Java

1. in the middle tab, Java, check the runtime parameters of the enabled java. Maybe Java can't even run at the test person's PC.
2. in the rightmost tab, Advanced, turn on the 'show console' and all the 3 debugging check boxes (enable tracing/ logging/ applet lifecycle exceptions)

now you should be able to see the exact exception

Answer (score -1):

A JAR is not 32-bit or 64-bit, it can run on either JVM. Probably you are using a native library( dll or exe for example) which is platform dependent.

If you are using a native library, then use the specific native library according to the the platform. Use 64 bit native library for a 64 bit platform/os and 32 bit native library for 32 bit platform.